# how To mine Bitcoin With Server?

Tags: script, server, php, cpu-mining

I have some server on hostinger.
there is any software or script with that I can mine for with one time setting....
I tried for php script search in Google but can't find
Sorry for my poor English
Pls give miner or script and pool's name link......